# Change getter setters with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have several classes distributed across different packages in my Java projects which contain one or more attributes are corresponding getters and setters. I need to change the names of the attribute to include a prefix. For example if I have a variable

```
private String one;
```

I would like to change to

```
private String m_one;
```

Also I need the corresponding getters and setter to change. **The constraint here is that this has to be changed with ant-scripts.**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason behind Ant constraint? (Just eager to know it)

Comment: IMHO you should not change getter setters for change you have explained `getOne` makes more sense than `getM_one`

Comment: can I ask why do you want to break standard naming convention?

Comment: Why are you constrained to only use ant?  Ant does not seem to be the best tool for the job here.  While it does support pattern replacements across multiple files, this is a non-trivial case.  Identifying instance variables in java files would be hard to do with just pattern replacements.

Comment: I won't give you any hint to make your code worse! Such a member prefix is no clean code.

Comment: I understand that pattern replacement is hard using Ant. But this has to be done. Also this does not make my code worse., this is done to create unique variables across different projects.

Comment: Why should you care about variable (field!) names across projects? There's already the packages and classes that serve as namespaces: there's no confusing the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your java variable in java file with the help of below ant code

```
 <replaceregexp match="one" replace="m_one" flags="g" byline="true">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Comment: Thanks, already tried this. While this does the job for 1 variable, I dont understand how to make it work for all variables defined across several classes